# Magento 2: Cookies expiration time is not extended for customer

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.2

I have increase cookies lifetime for the customer but it not working.
After customer login, 1 to 2-hour customer stay login if he/she close browser then again start browser at that time customer need to log in again is anyone have an idea how to set cookies lifetime for a customer?

https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/3139974/13996c6bb53071581243f1695d6e80bb

Answer (score 0):

Look inside your server php.ini file

SSH in and type to found your php.ini location: php -i | grep "Loaded Configuration File"

Check:

## Lifetime in seconds of cookie or, if 0, until browser is restarted.

session.cookie_lifetime = 0

0 value= Clear session every time you restart the computer or close and open browser.

and

## After this number of seconds, stored data will be seen as 'garbage' and

## cleaned up by the garbage collection process.

session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440

1440 value Sec = 24 Minutes

both Values need to be at least: 86400

if you change this two values to 86400  your issue must be solved.

Answer (score 0):

In your php.ini file:

```
session.gc_maxlifetime 86400
```

If you have not changed this, it should be by default `1440` i.e. `24 minutes`. Change it to `86400` for one day session lifetime                 & On the Admin sidebar, go to **Stores > Settings > Configuration**.

If you have multiple stores, set the Store View chooser in the upper-right corner to the store where the configuration applies.

In the panel on the **left under General, choose Web**.

Expand the Default Cookie Settings section.

Default Cookie Settings

To change the default, clear the Use system value checkbox and enter the new value in seconds.

Click Save Config.

Check this one This will be helpful - https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/customers/customer-online-options.html